# When i developing android applications, under what scenarios should i use EventBus?There is anything needs attention?

Tags: android

I used EventBus for message communication between asyncronous and UI thread, there is anything need attentions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same using interfaces.

It actually totally depends on the scenario, in case of tight-coupling you, where many classes are dependent on each other, you should use Event Bus.

Let's say you have an Activity, which is hosting one fragment A, and fragment A contains another fragment B, and on click of a button in fragment B, you want to communicate, with the Activity, you can do it, by using interface, but the classes are highly coupled and you need to pass the implementation from Activity to fragment A to fragment B.

It would be much easier, if you use event Bus, in this scenario.

Now, Consider a situation, where in you Activity is just hosting one fragment and you want to communicate between these two. In this case, interface would be a good choice. 
Using Event Bus here, won't be a good decision as it loops through all the registered indexes class and then post to the subscribed method.

Answer (score 0):

EventBus is a library in Android studio. I guess it's for you to pass a message from one class to another or more classes. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: We can achieve the same using interface, but what's the deference between two ways?